# Undefined method `stringify_keys' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive an "NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for 1:Fixnum, " error, any suggestions?

```
def self.gen_group(name, score, units = {})
  transaction do
    g = Group.create(name: name)
    units.each do |name, number|
      g.members.create(unit_id: Unit.find_by(name: name.to_s).id, amount: number)
    end
    g               
  end   
end
```

My method call:

```
g1 = Group.gen_group("Waldor's Slugs", :Pikeman => 5, :Archer => 4, :Wizard => 1)
```

Comment: Hard to say, but I notice you have variable 'name' overlap. created once with method input and second when you iterate over your units.

Comment: Try to use, g.members.create(unit_id: Unit.where(name: name.to_s).first.id, amount: number)

Comment: @manis Did removing the `score` (see my answer below) fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash `:Pikeman => 5, :Archer => 4, :Wizard => 1` is assigned to `score` (which is not used in the method) and not to `units`.

If your intention is to loop over the `:Pikeman => ...` hash in `units.each`, then just remove the obsolete `score` from the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

In your method call, try:

```
g1 = Group.gen_group("Waldor's Slugs", "Pikeman" => "5", "Archer" => "4", "Wizard" => "1")
```

I forget the details, but in a few places in Rails you can't rely on the symbol form (:Pikeman) being interchangeable with the string form ("Pikeman") in a hash. You can experiment with the method call to see if it's also necessary to send in the values as strings.

Comment: Since he converts the key to String with `name.to_s`, both Symbol and String keys will behave the same. Besides, for a normal Hash, Symbol and String keys are never interchangable. You'd have to use HashWithIndifferentAccess for that.